# Resigning due to ill health UK

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, health, mental-health

I have a progressive neurological disorder - I won't be going into the details of the illness as its private and personal and quite emotive. A year ago I spoke to my then line manager, that this day would come and that I would be resigning due to physiological and cognitive decline.

**What do I need to provide to resign with the minimum of fuss due to ill health?**

Especially as my new line manager and HR can't find any notes on my staff record regarding last years discussion (I can easily dig out paperwork from my GP & Consultant). Currently they are engaging with me to discuss alternative working arrangements and to retract my resignation. I am currently signed off work, due to the impact on my mental health as well.

Comment: You don't need anything. You don't need a reason to resign, just do it.

Comment: "Currently they are engaging with me to discuss alternative working arrangements and to retract my resignation"  It is your choice, not theirs, if you want to resign.  You are not a slave.

Comment: If you are currently signed off work, there is no need for you to resign. You simply continue in that state indefinitely. It's up to your employer to dismiss you if they feel there is no further prospect of getting useful work out of you. In some cases, you may be entitled to a medical retirement or similar conditions.

Comment: @Steve, but I've already handed over my resignation. No one has mentioned any of the things you outline, where would I have found out that information?

Comment: @Ourjamie, I'd suggest you go to a CAB, and possibly contact your union if you have one, and tell your employer as soon as possible in writing that you have sent the resignation in an unbalanced mental condition and that you withdraw it and are seeking advice. I assume given your condition, the retraction will be accepted, and is probably why HR have not accepted it thus far - the law says employers cannot seize on resignations in the heat of the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that you provide written notification to your manager stating something along the lines of

> I wish to resign from my employment at <X>, effective immediately.

You then work out your notice and your employment is over.

However, this is complicated by the fact you are currently signed off; I would suggest talking to your local Citizen's Advice, but the bottom line is you are always free to resign. Your employer can of course attempt negotiate with you about alternative working arrangements, but you are under no obligation to accept and if you have actually submitted written notification of your resignation, "the clock is ticking" and your employment will terminate at the end of your notice period.

Comment: I resigned during my time sick, my meds had been changed to reduce the tremors, taking me off anti anxieties, but had some bad side effects one being continuous headaches and deep depression. I've deteriorated quite a bit during lock-down. I'm probably going to remain on sick leave during my 3 month notice period. Also the resignation hasn't been actioned, so is it valid from the time I handed it over or from the from the time I say please accept it?

Comment: @Ourjamie: Ideally you write the date of your last working day in the resignation letter, and base that on the date that you hand it to the company. That makes everything clear. The company does not need to formally "accept" it before notice period starts, and it does not *need* to be subject to negotiations, except perhaps if you and company both feel like agreeing a mutually good date. I would suggest *you* decide which start date applies and write a follow up letter clarifying what your last working day for the company will be - that is presuming you are still set on resigning in your case.

Comment: @Ourjamie This is getting too close to legal advice for this (or any other) Stack Exchange site. It seems unlikely your employer will try to keep you in a state of employment longer than they have to, but it could depend on exactly how you worded your resignation and what you've said since. I would seriously suggest talking to Citizen's Advice if you feel you can manage that; if not, you need to talk to your doctors.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer and also state that it should be closed as there was a legal element that I was unaware of